# NodeJs authentication for sites behind NTLM auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, phantomjs, ntlm

So, I need to run some JS for testing a couple sites, but the crutch is that it is behind NTLM auth. This brings me to my question is how to authenticate JS when the site behind NTLM? I know that ( i believe for phantomjs) you can use

```
    page.settings.username  = ....
    page.settings.pwd       = ....
```

Works for basic auth but not NTLM. Anyone know of some way of authenticating sites behind NTLM?

Comment: This is probably the best working thing out there. https://www.npmjs.org/package/ntlm and https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm also works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved using https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm.